# Clickhouse - Output each array item and its index/position

Tags: clickhouse

In Clickhouse I have an array column. 
Can I output each value in the array and its corresponding index/position (+1) within?

So given ['c','b','a'] I would like to output

```
key        position
c          1
b          2
a          3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select a,i from 
     (select  ['c','b','a'] arr)
      array join arr as a, arrayEnumerate(arr) as i
┌─a─┬─i─┐
│ c │ 1 │
│ b │ 2 │
│ a │ 3 │
└───┴───┘



select  (arrayJoin(arrayZip(arr, arrayEnumerate(arr))) as x).1 a, x.2 i
from 
     (select  ['c','b','a'] arr)
┌─a─┬─i─┐
│ c │ 1 │
│ b │ 2 │
│ a │ 3 │
└───┴───┘
```

Comment: Thanks very much Denis